# Getting error while running reactjs build from nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, build, production

Please someone help me. I am new to nodejs.
I am Getting the following error while run node program. i am trying to connect reactjs to nodejs for

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
main.b4ed36d8.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error."
```

Comment: how you are connecting react with node?

Comment: We need more information. Are you trying to deploy a monolith application i.e. client and server? Can you list the commands you're running?